# File still tracking even after I created a .gitignore file - VSCode

Tags: git

I am using Visual Studio Code. I am trying to ignore the file Python.py. I created a .gitignore file and I added the filename Python.py then saved my changes. The image can be seen below:

[image]

But when I type >git status it still seems to be tracking the file.

Answer (score -2):

It's still being tracked because you committed the file previously.

To fix this, use [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) like so:

```
git rm --cached -r Python.py
```